# get time from clockpicker and then write the time to mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I use https://github.com/weareoutman/clockpicker for setting time.

```js
$('.clockpicker-with-callbacks').clockpicker({
    donetext: 'Done',
    afterDone: function() {
      console.log(this.value);
    }
  })
  .find('input').change(function() {
    console.log(this.value);
  });
if (/Mobile/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
  $('input').prop('readOnly', true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='clearfix'>
  <div class='input-group clockpicker-with-callbacks'>

    <input type='text' class='form-control' value='10:10'>

    <span class='input-group-addon'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'>
    
    </span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

So. I need some how write the input time to mysql data base. And it must be done in **afterDone: function()**

Please, help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make an ajax call to another php script that would store the result in your database

```
 $.post( "path/file.php", { 
            var_time: this.value
        }).done(function( data, status ) {

         console.log('data: '+data+' status: '+status);

         if(data == 'success' && status == 'success'){      

         }else{

         }
      }
);
```

The `console.log('data: '+data+' status: '+status);` will display the output of your other script, don't forget to sanitize the user input ;)

Comment: don't understand how `$input_time=$_POST[var_time'];`

Comment: I edited my answer to match those values. `var_time: this.value` the part before the `:` is the key and on the other side is the value, meaning `$_POST['var_time']`

Comment: Can I use in `path/file.php` this -> `$_POST['var_time']`

Comment: Yes, what message do you get in the console ?

Comment: It's 'data:    status: success'

Comment: why is 'data' blank?

Comment: Your php script does not output anything. I like to validate if there is no error to output\echo `success`, this way you can also notify the user in case of an error

Comment: Is it should be `success`? Like status is?

Comment: This part of code `.find('input').change(function() {
    console.log(this.value);
  });` work fine. It returns the time if I change time...

Comment: `data` is what is returned by the php script, you decide what `data` is...

Comment: `data` and `this.value` are not the same thing?

Comment: No, data is what file.php outputs

Comment: Actualy, it's empty... I need add this `var attime = $('#attime').val();` before your code. Anyway, thank you a lot. You did help.

Comment: Uh, oh well :P glad I could help 